# DVC shows files not tracked in source control in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dvc

I'm using DVC extension in VScode inside a python project. The problem is that dvc shows files not tracked by dvc in the source control panel! As in the following picture.
DVC track only data folder and not the src folder. How can I fix it? Have you also encountered these problems?

[image]

Comment: I can't follow you. are you asking why those untracked files are untracked? -> because you did not add them.   what is "the data folder"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files shown are completely untracked. They are shown in both SCM trees so you can add them to either Git or DVC using inline actions.
Once the files are tracked by one of the tools they should only show up under the appropriate tree.

Comment: Each new file with the .py extension should not be automatically added under the git tree?

Comment: New files within a Git-based project start off as untracked (U). In order to track them with Git, you need to stage and commit them.